# using mediaelement as player for list returned by mysql query

Tags: mediaelement.js

I am building a site which has a catalouge of MP3s and a mysql database of the same tracks. I run queries, which return matching tracks in a list - by each of the tracks I have a download option and - currently - a flash player. As it is loaded for each returned track it makes the page very heavy to load.

Now I would like to replace this with a simple audio player that sits at the top of the page and a link in each returned track name to make the player play that track (a link that 'sends' this track to the audio player)

searching online brought me here but before I start learning how to implement and use this player I would like to know if it is possible to use it the way I want and if so can you suggest a way of implementing it to this extent..

Answer (score 0):

```
function playme(src){

var getAudioSource = src; //pass a link's attribute as a parameter, i.e. <a href="etc" name="linktomp3.mp3></a>"

var mymp3 = new MediaElementPlayer('#mymp3', {
     translationSelector: true,
     success: function (mediaElement) {

        var sources = [{ src: getAudioSource, type: 'audio/mp3' }];

        mediaElement.setSrc(sources);
        mediaElement.pause();
        mediaElement.load(); }
     });
}
```